SQL query Error, Dynamic SQL query is not returning the value
I have JSON as follows:
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{
"results": [
{
  "tables": [
    {
      "rows": [
        {
          "[department_id]": 1111,
          "[company_id]":12345,
          "[sum]": 38204410879
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
]}';

and I have a table like below
results(id, date, key_1, key_2, key_3, key_4, key_4, value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4, value_5)

I want to generate dynamic SQL to iterate over the JSON to create an insert query to my result table.

The last value will always be the sum, so save 38204410879 to value_1 columns.

all the other values wants to save to the key columns in the order
eg:key_1= 1111, key_2= 12345


the JSON may change so I want to do this in a dynamic manner.
What I did so far, I have some SQL, which takes the count and create the keys dynamically, but when I try to get the values, its not working
DECLARE @i INT = 0;

DECLARE @total_count INT = 3;

DECLARE @key NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Loop through the JSON object to extract keys and values

WHILE @i < @total_count

BEGIN

SET @key = CONCAT(', (SELECT [value] FROM OPENJSON(@json, ''$.results[0].tables[0].rows[0]'') WITH (keyIndex INT ''$."$id" '') AS jsonKeys

                    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(@json, ''$.results[0].tables[0].rows[0]'')

                    WHERE jsonKeys.keyIndex = ', @i, ')');

PRINT @key;

SET @i = @i + 1;

END

Then I will append this SQL to my main SQL to complete the value session.
Sample print statement for the first iteration
SELECT [value]
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.results[0].tables[0].rows[0]') WITH (keyIndex INT '$."$id" ') AS jsonKeys
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(@json, '$.results[0].tables[0].rows[0]')
WHERE jsonKeys.keyIndex = 0

but its returning empty
sample output query would be below
insert into result(date,key_1,key_2,value_1)values(getdate(),111,12345,38204410879)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

When you say "not working" - what actually is happening? And what does the PRINT statement return?

It was already pointed out that it is better to use key-value pairs table design for your scenario.

@DaleK question updated with the example print statement

@YitzhakKhabinsky 'key-value pairs table design' can you share more details

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

OPENJSON is only available in MSSQL 2016 and above.  lots of 2014 around still.

Here is key-value approach. Regardless of the dynamic nature of JSON fragment inside "rows" array it will work.
dbfiddle
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'{
    "results": [
        {
            "tables": [
                {
                    "rows": [
                        {
                            "[department_id]": 1111,
                            "[company_id]": 12345,
                            "[sum]": 38204410879
                        },
                        {
                            "[department_id]": 22,
                            "[company_id]": 770
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}';

DECLARE @tbl TABLE (seq INT, _key sysname, _value NVARCHAR(1024));
-- DDL and sample data population, end

INSERT INTO @tbl (seq, _key, _value)
SELECT d.[key] AS seq, TRIM('[]' FROM r.[key]) AS [key], r.[value]
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.results[0].tables[0].rows') AS d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.value) AS r;

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

Output



seq
key
value




0
department_id
1111


0
company_id
12345


0
sum
38204410879


1
department_id
22


1
company_id
770




Thanks for the insight Yitzhak.  based on my logic after this select, i have to iterate again to get the last value as value_1 and all other values as key for my result table. can we do the same in single statement. can you help me with some ideas? Thanks

I slightly modified the answer. It looks like you can just add a WHERE clause to filter out not needed rows based on the seq column values.

Thanks a lot, based on the new select result, can you help me with the insert statement to my result table mentioned above, i am stuck with that now.

i have tries the above code, but its not working as expected.
TRIM('[]' FROM r.[key]), is not working so i used 'REPLACE(REPLACE(d.[key], '[', ''), ']', '') AS [key]' and it works
again with the table keyword shows error, i am working in Microsoft SQL management studio, does that cause an error

It means you SQL Server is below 2017. Such TRIM() function functionality is working starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards. You can check your version by issuing the following: SELECT @@VERSION; Please don't miss my comment under your original question.

Incorrect syntax near 'TABLE'.

checked Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.34905.0

The answer is following the same  minimal reproducible example pattern. You copy it to SSMS as-is, run it, and it is working.

I added a dbfiddle link to the answer for you to see a working example.

as mentioned i did update the sample output in the question as well. Thanks

also, considering my mentioned result table, this is different right?
my sample result table
'results(id, date, key_1, key_2, key_3, key_4, key_4, value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4, value_5)'
and expected output would be a query like below
'insert into result(date,key_1,key_2,value_1)values(getdate(),111,12345,38204410879)'

Instead of going horizontally, the answer is following key-value approach, i.e. row wise vertically. It allows to handle a dynamic nature of JSON.

but here how can i do the parsing from temp table to my result table. can you show me an example with my result table. Thanks

You need to change your approach to key-value pairs. The @tbl in the answer is your final table!

You can add to that table a primary key and date columns.
